# Changing directory in the for loop in the batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to write one batch script, which will copy the "am_test.txt" from the sub-directory to the new path, but i am facing difficulty in changing the path inside the for loop. In my batch script following line is not working "cd !temp!\testdata". Can anyone tells me the reason:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto:main
goto:eof

:main
setlocal
for /d %%x in (*) DO (
   set temp=%%~fx
   echo !temp!
   cd !temp!\testdata
   copy am_test*.txt E:\Work_folder
)
endlocal
```

Comment: I think you may have meant to use, `Call :main`, you shouldn't use a local variable named the same as a System Variable, `%temp%`, and there's absolutely no reason to `CD` to the directory, just to copy. Try `Copy "%%~fx\testdata\am_test*.txt" "E:\Work_folder"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem pushd popd
for /d %%x in (*) do (echo ---& echo fx: "%%~fx") & (pushd "%%x") && (echo cd: "!cd!") & popd

rem cd
for /d %%x in (*) do (echo ---& echo fx: "%%~fx") & (cd "%%x") & echo cd: "!cd!"

exit /b
```

To understand what is causing the issue, create a script
that does similar though isolates the issue. The code above
shows the similar issue.

Created folders in drive `Z:` with names of `a`, `b` and `c`.

Script output is

```
---
fx: "Z:\a"
cd: "Z:\a"
---
fx: "Z:\b"
cd: "Z:\b"
---
fx: "Z:\c"
cd: "Z:\c"
---
fx: "Z:\a"
cd: "Z:\a"
---
fx: "Z:\a\b"
The system cannot find the path specified.
cd: "Z:\a"
---
fx: "Z:\a\c"
The system cannot find the path specified.
cd: "Z:\a"
```

The `pushd` and `popd` succeeded and looks correct.
The current directory is restored before the next iteration.

The `cd` succeeds with `a` though fails with `b` and `c`.
The fail is based on iterating `*` folders while changing
directory in the loop and not restoring it.
As the folders returned are relative names to the initial current directory,
the paths of `%%~fx` may not be valid as the system is using the full
path of current directory joined with the iterated folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing what your code appears to be intended to do.

As a batch file:

```bat
@For /D %%A In (*) Do @If Exist "%%A\testdata\am_test*.txt" Copy "%%A\testdata\am_test*.txt" "E:\Work_folder">Nul
```

At the Command Prompt:

```bat
For /D %A In (*) Do @If Exist "%A\testdata\am_test*.txt" Copy "%A\testdata\am_test*.txt" "E:\Work_folder">Nul
```

*In either case, `E:\Work_folder` must exist.*